# How to find the value of h to make the matrix consistent

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I evaluate the value of h to make this matrix a consistent linear system

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&h&4\\3&6&8\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Augment the matrix and solve the system.  You'll finish with some "function" of h. Solve that for h.

Comment: Is this the augmented matrix of the linear system?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use Gaussian Elimination in order to obtain an augmented matrix that is in echelon form. The last row should have the form:
$$
[ 0 ~~ f(h) ~~ |~~ b]
$$
where $b \neq 0$ and $f(h)$ is some function of $h$. Recall that the system is consistent iff there is no row of the form:
$$
[ 0 ~~ 0 ~~ |~~ b]
$$
with $b \neq 0$. So to find the permissible values of $h$, just solve the inequality:
$$
f(h) \neq 0
$$